# XAML - Button Image not showing up when I Debug

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

So here's my code:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Button Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image Source="Assets\Images\FlashOff.jpg"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

The button background image shows up fine in the Visual Studio, but when I debug, the image won't show up. The functionality of the button is still there. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I tried it in Visual Studio 2012 as well with no luck. Is there a different way to stretch a button to the grid and display the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use forward slash (/) instead of back-slash (\).

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Button Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image Source="Assets/Images/FlashOff.jpg"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've been so used to folder paths and I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Just an FYI, resharper added back-slashes when I moved some images. I stupidly expected it to do the right thing and ran into this same problem.